# How to convert a nested array in a json file into a matrix and a table in LaTeX

Tags: luatex, json

I would like to read a nested array such as the following in a json file into the LaTeX and convert it into a matrix with each base array becoming a row, and a table with each base array becoming a column.

```
"G": [
            [
                0.6170212765957448,
                0.3829787234042552,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                -0.0062734226435906225,
                0.0
            ],
            [
                0.23404255319148953,
                0.7659574468085104,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                -0.006077066178884076,
                0.0
            ],
            [
                0.0,
                0.9075630252100839,
                0.09243697478991603,
                0.0,
                -0.004923272683698053,
                -0.002819495369518709
            ]
  ]
```

I suppose I need to use LuaTeX. But I do not know exactly how to carry it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LuaTeX has a builtin JSON parser which can be accessed via `utilities.json`.  It provides the function `load` which takes a filename and return a Lua table containing the JSON data.  Then you can just use nested for loops to iterate over your data and `tex.sprint` to print it to the document.

Before you can start you have to turn your file in the valid JSON though.  To this end you have to wrap it into an object:

```
{
    "G": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

I saved it as `test.json`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
userdata = utilities.json.load("test.json")
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{luacode*}
local G = userdata.G
tex.sprint("\\begin{pmatrix}")
for i = 1, #G do
    for j = 1, #G[i] do
        tex.sprint(G[i][j] .. (j == #G[i] and " \\\\" or " & "))
    end
end
tex.sprint("\\end{pmatrix}")
\end{luacode*}
\]

\begin{luacode*}
local G = userdata.G
tex.sprint("\\begin{tabular}{" .. string.rep("c", #G) .. "}")
for i = 1, #G[1] do
    for j = 1, #G do
        tex.sprint(G[j][i] .. (j == #G and " \\\\" or " & "))
    end
end
tex.sprint("\\end{tabular}")
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I put your code into Overleaf. But the matrix does not show up. There is no error message either. How to fix it?

Comment: @Hans Works for me https://www.overleaf.com/read/qkdjqrcktkrg

Comment: Thank you. The problem I found was that the TeX Live Version was 2017 (legacy). It now works under the 2019 version. +1 and accepted.

Comment: Could you please explain the syntax such as .. (j == #G[i] and " \\\\" or " & ") ? Thank you.

Comment: @Hans That's Lua's form of the ternary operator.  http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator

Comment: @Hans Yes, you can.  Why don't you just try?

Answer (score 4):

My solution is based mostly on TeX primitives. First, we scan the matrix data by `\scanmatrix` macro. Data are stored in the `\matrixdata` macro in the form:

```
0.6170212765957448&0.3829787234042552&0.0&0.0&-0.0062734226435906225&0.0\cr 0.23404255319148953&...\cr ...
```

The maximal width of data item is saved to `\maxitemwidth` when the data are scanned.

Then we can use `\matrixdata` inside `\halign` primitive to print the data row to row. Or we can use `\valign` primitive to print the data column to column. The same `\matrixdata` are used in both cases.

```
\newdimen\maxitemwidth
\def\iscomma#1,#2\iffalse{\ifx^#2^}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}    

\def\scanmatrix#1[{\maxitemwidth=0pt \def\matrixdata{}\scanmatrixrow}
\def\scanmatrixrow #1[{\scanmatrixitem}
\def\scanmatrixitem #1#2 {\iscomma #1#2,\iffalse
   \savematrixitem #1#2,\addto\matrixdata{\cr}\expandafter\closematrixrow
   \else \savematrixitem #1#2\addto\matrixdata{&}\expandafter\scanmatrixitem \fi}
\def\closematrixrow #1]{\futurelet\next\closematrixrowA}
\def\closematrixrowA{\ifx\next,\expandafter\scanmatrixrow
   \else\expandafter\closematrix\fi}
\def\closematrix #1]{}
\def\savematrixitem #1,{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
   \ifdim\maxitemwidth<\wd0 \maxitemwidth=\wd0 \fi
   \addto\matrixdata{#1}}

\scanmatrix
"G": [
            [
                0.6170212765957448,
                0.3829787234042552,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                -0.0062734226435906225,
                0.0
            ],
            [
                0.23404255319148953,
                0.7659574468085104,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                -0.006077066178884076,
                0.0
            ],
            [
                0.0,
                0.9075630252100839,
                0.09243697478991603,
                0.0,
                -0.004923272683698053,
                -0.002819495369518709
            ]
  ]

% print matrix row to row:

\halign{\hfil$#$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$#$\hfil\cr \matrixdata}

\bigskip

% print transposed matrix:

\valign{&\hsize=\dimexpr\maxitemwidth+5pt \leftskip=0pt plus1fil 
   \noindent\strut $#$\cr \matrixdata}
```

Comment: You seem to have missed the process of extracting the dictionary from the json file.

Comment: Interesting approach (+1) but I think OP requires full JSON support.